# how to query filter self foreign key

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

> ```
>     query = Services.objects.filter(parent_id__isnull=True,sub_service__type=0)
> ```

When im filtering `sub_service__type=1` It returns correct output. i.e. `type 1` for `sub_service`,  But when i change it to `sub_service__type=0`  `filters` doesnot work. Instead it returns me every output. i.e. `type 0,1` Instead of `type 0`

Heres Code:

```
# MODELS

class Services(models.Model):
    type_ = ((1, 'INCLUSIVE'),
             (0, 'EXCLUSIVE'))
    service_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    parent_id = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name='sub_service')
    type = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, choices=type_)


# VIEWS

@action(detail=False, methods=['get'], permission_classes=(AllowAny,))
def service_list(self, request):

    query = Services.objects.filter(parent_id__isnull=True,sub_service__type=0)
    serializer = ServiceSerializer(query , many=True).data
    return Response(serializer)


# SERIALIZER

class SubServiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Services
        fields = "__all__"


class ServiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sub_service = SubServiceSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Services
        fields = "__all__"
```

Comment: With `sub_service__type=1` you simply retrieve all `Service`s that have *at least* one related `Subservice` with `type=1`, but there can be other related `Subservice`s with a different type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you filter with `sub_service__type=1` you retrieve *all* `Service`s that have *at least* one related `Service` with `type=1`. But it is thus allowed that there are other related sub-`Service`s with a different type. The `.sub_service` manager will furthermore *not* filter the queryset of related objects.

You can make use of a [**`Prefetch`** object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch) to filter the relation as well:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

query = Services.objects.filter(
    parent_id__isnull=True,sub_service__type=0
).prefetch_related(Prefetch('sub_service', Service.objects.filter(type=0)))
```